# Can't find correct version of WebHostBuilderContext in a multitarget project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a project that was originally targeting net472, and now must be converted to target both net472 and net5.0.

After I've added net5.0 to  it became impossible to build the project because wherever there is mention of WebHostBuilderContext, it uses the version from the net472 package (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions), and not the newer version from net5.0 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref), causing type mismatch(they are considered different types).

Apparently since netcore2.1 there has been a large change regarding the Hosting namespace, and I need to somehow instruct the IDE to use the correct version of the mentioned class depending on the build target.

There is no explicit reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref in this project, they are transitively included from other dependencies, so I can't find a way to make use of aliases to explicitly point to the correct assembly. When I use precompiler directives it always sees the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions and doesn't recognize the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref version.

How can I solve this dependency hell?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against having one ASP.NET project that is both .net framework 4.x and .net (core) 5.0. That's compatibility hell and asking for problems. If you need specific data from the Context in other projects, consider building a layer of abstraction ([adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) pattern) and only provide (e.g. inject) a framework-independent interface to the other modules.